# Add some words to one column of text film based on linux system?

Tags: linux, text, awk, sed

like this, two columns, however, not only three lines

```
1   21
1   21
1   21
```

...

to become

```
1   a21
1   a21
1   a21
```

...

still two columns, just add **same word** "a", I guess maybe can be solve by “**awk**” or “**sed**”, but didn't find how to realize this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sed solution:

```
sed -e 's/  */&a/'
```

With extended regexes (`-E` or `-r`):

```
sed -E 's/ +/&a/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk '{print "a"$2}' file
```

Using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
sed -E 's/^[0-9]+[[:blank:]]+/&a/g' file
```

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) in substitution mode, like sed :

```
perl -pe 's/^\d+\s+/$&a/ file
```

Comment: Many thanks! And I forgot to mention between the two lines is tab, so I'm not sure the [[:blank:]] by using sed